# after installing ubuntu14.04 alongside windows 10 after few days windows not starting

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 10, but now my windows 10 will NOT boot. When i tryed recover it again it failed. Clueless new to Linux need help. How can i recover my Windows 10 and correctly duel boot my computer?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using GRUB? i.e you get a list of options to boot to .. Ubuntu .. Windows etc.

If you're at that point and windows is listed then the issue is probably with windows; as that menu just passes control over to the windows bootloader. So there's no issue with Linux.
The windows repair can be problematic at most times, like never finding a problem and just wanting to reboot. You might be able to boot into [Safe mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-10/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode) to try find the issue. Just keep hitting SHIFT after you choose windows basically, it's a pain to get sometimes.

Be aware that if you repair or have to reinstall Windows it might overwrite grub so you'll only be able to boot windows until you reinstall GRUB again. [Here's a link just in case](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd)

Comment: I think i lost my windows , but still thank you for your help.